# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android

I'm not understanding the reason for the error, as the "Resultado" class was declared in Manifest. Can anyone help? Thank you!

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="uerj.normal">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Menu_Principal">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Entrada_Dados">
    <activity android:name=".Resultado" />
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Code

My code basically consists of a Result activity in order to calculate and display the related results.

```
package uerj.normal;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Entrada_Dados extends AppCompatActivity{

    // DECLARANDO AS VARIÁVEIS

    public EditText txt_normal;
    public EditText txt_momento;
    public EditText txt_largura;
    public EditText txt_altura;
    public EditText txt_resistencia_concreto;
    public EditText txt_cobrimento;
    public EditText txt_numero_barras_linha_compressao;
    public Spinner cmb_diametro_barra_compressao;
    public EditText txt_numero_barras_linha_tracao;
    public Spinner cmb_diametro_barra_tracao;
    public String [] diametro_barra = new String[]{"6,3", "8", "10", "12,5", "16", "20", "22", "25", "32", "40"};
    public EditText txt_altura_util;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entrada__dados);

        // RELACIONANDO VARIÁVEIS COM COMPONENTES

        txt_normal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_normal);
        txt_momento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_momento);
        txt_largura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_largura);
        txt_altura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_altura);
        txt_resistencia_concreto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_resistencia_concreto);
        txt_cobrimento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_cobrimento);
        txt_numero_barras_linha_compressao = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_numero_barras_linha_compressao);
        cmb_diametro_barra_compressao = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cmb_diametro_barra_compressao);
        txt_numero_barras_linha_tracao = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_numero_barras_linha_tracao);
        cmb_diametro_barra_tracao = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cmb_diametro_barra_tracao);
        txt_altura_util = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_altura_util);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, diametro_barra);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cmb_diametro_barra_compressao.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, diametro_barra);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cmb_diametro_barra_tracao.setAdapter(adapter);

        // EVENTO NO BOTÃO

        final Button btn_resultado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_resultado);
        btn_resultado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (txt_normal.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_normal.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a solicitação Normal Nd");

                else if (txt_momento.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_momento.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a solicitação Momento Md");

                else if (txt_largura.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_largura.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a largura da seção");

                else if (txt_altura.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_altura.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a altura da seção");

                else if (txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a resistência do concreto");

                else if (txt_cobrimento.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_cobrimento.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o cobrimento");

                else if (txt_numero_barras_linha_compressao.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_numero_barras_linha_compressao.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o número de barras");

                else if (txt_numero_barras_linha_tracao.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_numero_barras_linha_tracao.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha o número de barras");

                else if (txt_altura_util.getText().toString().equals("")||txt_altura_util.getText().toString().equals("."))
                    showError("Campos em branco", "Preencha a altura útil da seção");

                else {

                    Intent it = new Intent (Entrada_Dados.this, Resultado.class);

                    it.putExtra("txt_numero_barras_linha_compressao", txt_numero_barras_linha_compressao.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("cmb_diametro_barra_compressao", cmb_diametro_barra_compressao.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    it.putExtra("txt_numero_barras_linha_tracao", txt_numero_barras_linha_tracao.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("cmb_diametro_barra_tracao", cmb_diametro_barra_tracao.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    it.putExtra("txt_altura_util", txt_altura_util.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("txt_altura", txt_altura.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("txt_cobrimento", txt_cobrimento.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("txt_largura", txt_largura.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("txt_resistencia_concreto", txt_resistencia_concreto.getText().toString());

                    startActivity(it);

                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void showError(String title, String err){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(err);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Error

[image]

Comment: Please show the code where you start that Activity

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its some code wrong here in the manifest

```
...
<activity android:name=".Entrada_Dados">
<activity android:name=".Resultado" />
</activity>
```

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
...
<activity android:name=".Entrada_Dados"/>
<activity android:name=".Resultado" />
```